# Is there a way to find the first element to match a Predicate?

Tags: java, performance, filtering, predicate, java-stream

With Java 8+, you can easily find all elements of a collection that match a [`Predicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html).

```java
someCollection.stream().filter(somePredicate)
```

You could then find the first element:

```java
someCollection.stream().filter(somePredicate).findFirst()
```

The problem with this, though, is that it runs the `Predicate` against all the elements. Is there a clean way to only run the `Predicate` against elements until the first match is found, and then return it, like `anyMatch` does (but returns a `boolean` telling if one was found)?

Comment: What makes you think it goes through all of the elements of the `Stream`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does exactly what you want. It doesn't run over all the elements. The `filter` method creates a stream and on top of it `findFirst` creates another stream.

So when you try to get the element of the stream that was created after `findFirst()` you'll get only the first one that matches the predicate.

Best way to check that is to add a print line or something like that inside the predicate.

Create a stream of integers for example from 0 to 10 and create a predicate that prints the number and then checks if it's divided by 3. You'll get this printed out: 0, 1, 2, 3 and that's it.

I wrote a question + answer in the past to explain in more details how it works: [Understanding java 8 stream's filter method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26687937/2083523)

Comment: @Pietu1998 - I edited the question and it contains a link to an answer + question of mine that better explains this.